# JGROUPSPING table not cleaned up and causing cluster splits while restart

Tags: jgroups

I have tried upgrading our jgroups cluster from version 3.2.9 to 4.0.8. After upgrading I am facing two issues:

1. The entries that are added to JGROUPSPING table are not cleared even after the node leaves the cluster (killed using -9). Because of that the number of entries in the table increases as and when we do restarts for the maintenance. More entries in the cluster is also causing the cluster to come up very late.
2. With more entries in JGROUPSPING table, the cluster is not formed properly resulting in partitions and no merging is also happening. Because of that nodes are not known to each other causing functional issues. I am also observing FLUSH timeout is few nodes intermittently.

The TCP stack details are:

```
<TCP_NIO2 bind_port="7800" recv_buf_size="${tcp.recv_buf_size:20M}" send_buf_size="${tcp.send_buf_size:640K}" max_bundle_size="64K" sock_conn_timeout="300" thread_pool.enabled="false" thread_pool.min_threads="0" thread_pool.max_threads="0" thread_pool.keep_alive_time="5000"/>

<JDBC_PING connection_username="root" connection_driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" connection_password="" connection_url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db" />

<MERGE3 min_interval="5000" max_interval="10000"/>

<FD_SOCK suspect_msg_interval="10000" start_port="7900" port_range="10"/>

<FD timeout="20000" max_tries="3" />

<VERIFY_SUSPECT timeout="15000" num_msgs="3"/>

<pbcast.NAKACK2 use_mcast_xmit="false"
                xmit_interval="1000"
                log_not_found_msgs="true"
                discard_delivered_msgs="true"/>

<UNICAST3 log_not_found_msgs="true"  xmit_interval="1000"/>

<pbcast.STABLE stability_delay="100" desired_avg_gossip="60000" max_bytes="5M"/>

<pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true"
            join_timeout="5000"
            leave_timeout="1000"/>

<FRAG2 frag_size="60K"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pbcast.GMS print_local_addr="true"
                merge_timeout="15000"
                join_timeout="5000"
                max_join_attempts="5"
                leave_timeout="1000"/>

<pbcast.FLUSH start_flush_timeout="5000"/>
```

The view merge happens in two steps, one Flush operation and collecting merge response from all the members of each candidate view.

So the actual merge timeout is a sum of these operation timeouts.

```
merge_timeout = start_flush_timeout + merge_response_timeout;
//merge_response_timeout is an internally calculated.
merge_response_timeout = merge_timeout/2;
```

So to configure the merge timeout value you must consider start_flush_timeout  also.

For example my configuration was

```
merge_timeout = 15000 and  start_flush_timeout  = 10000;
So actual merge operation was taking (10000 + 15000/2) = 17500 which timed out after 15000 as configured with merge_timeout
```

Changed my configuration to **merge_timeout= 15000** and  **start_flush_timeout = 5000**, so the total timeout comes under **5000 + (15000/2) = 12500** which is less than total time out 15000 solved my problem.